# how to properly import csv data set using kite-dataset partitioned schema?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, hadoop-partitioning, kite-dataset

I'm working with the publicly-available csv dataset from MovieLens
I have created a partitioned dataset for the ratings.csv:

```
kite-dataset create ratings --schema rating.avsc --partition-by year-month.json --format parquet
```

Here is my year-month.json:

```
[ {
  "name" : "year",
  "source" : "timestamp",
  "type" : "year"
}, {
  "name" : "month",
  "source" : "timestamp",
  "type" : "month"
} ]
```

Here is my csv import command:

```
mkite-dataset csv-import ratings.csv ratings
```

After the import finished, I ran this command to see whether year and month partitions where in fact created:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/ratings/
```

What I've noticed, is that only a single year partition was created, and inside of it one a single month partition was created:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ml-20m]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/ratings/
Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2016-06-12 18:49 /user/hive/warehouse/ratings/.metadata
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2016-06-12 18:59 /user/hive/warehouse/ratings/.signals
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2016-06-12 18:59 /user/hive/warehouse/ratings/year=1970

[cloudera@quickstart ml-20m]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/ratings/year=1970/
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2016-06-12 18:59 /user/hive/warehouse/ratings/year=1970/month=01
```

What is the proper way to conduct such partitioned import, which would resulted in all years and all month partitions being created?

Answer (score 0):

Add three zeros in the end for the timestamp.

Use the below shell script to do it

```
#!/bin/bash

# add the CSV header to both files
head -n 1 ratings.csv > ratings_1.csv
head -n 1 ratings.csv > ratings_2.csv

# output the first 10,000,000 rows to ratings_1.csv
# this includes the header, and uses tail to remove it
head -n 10000001 ratings.csv | tail -n +2 | awk '{print "000" $1 }' >> ratings_1.csv

    enter code here

# output the rest of the file to ratings_2.csv
# this starts at the line after the ratings_1 file stopped
tail -n +10000002 ratings.csv | awk '{print "000" $1 }' >> ratings_2.csv
```

Even I had this problem, and it was resolved after adding 3 zeros.